# Unable to find dms.jar online to download

Tags: ojdbc

While writing a program to connect to Oracle 10g, I got an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/dms/instrument/ExecutionContextForJDBC

I understand that particular JAR file is missing. I have added `ojdbc14dms.jar`, still the issue persists. I explored that the class `ExecutionContextForJDBC` is available only in "`dms.jar` but unfortunately I am unable to locate any link through which I can download it.

Comment: How did you search for dms.jar? Maybe someone here can suggest a better search query.

Comment: I searched it through "http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/CatalogJar.htm" but unfortunately I did not find it there.

Comment: I recently had the same question and answered it on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563378/where-are-oracles-dms-class-files/17564700#17564700

Answer (score 0):

The dms.jar can be found on an installed oracle product.
You will not find this jar, for example, in the oracle 11g Xpress Edition.
You need to go to the commercial versions to find it.