# where are Oracle's DMS class files?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss

I'm running a JBoss server (inside Eclipse), with some Hibernate mixed in. I installed Oracle's ojdbc drivers from here:

[Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

I specifically downloaded the file: ojdbc6dms_g.jar, which according to the site contains instrumentation to support DMS. However when I startup my AS server, I get the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.dms.console.DMSConsole from [Module     
"com.oracle:main" from local module loader @485fcf29 (roots: /usr/local/jboss-7.1.1- 
final/modules)]
```

when the server is trying to get a new hibernate ejb exception.

I checked Oracle's jar file and sure enough it doesn't contain the class oracle.dms.console.DMSConsole, although from the notes on Oracle's site about the jar file, it seems like the jar file should contain the DMS classes.

Can anyone point me to the correct jar file? And when I do get the right file, where should this file be installed to, particularly with regards to Eclipse and JBoss?

**Update:** Just found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982945/uanble-to-find-dms-jar-online-to-download) asking the same thing here on SO.

Comment: http://www.findjar.com/class/oracle/dms/console/DMSConsole.html this tells it should be in `dms.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing classes are indeed in dms.jar. But as I've seen asked elsewhere finding the dms.jar file is not easy. You won't find dms.jar at [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) because as [noted by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html): dms.jar is not shipped as part of the RDBMS product. It is only available as part of the Oracle Application Server product.

I hopped onto our server and grabbed the jar file from our Oracle installation directory. We have 11g installed. With 11g you should be able to find the file here:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/oc4j/lib/dms.jar
```

Comment: The missing classes are also in the download ojdbc6dms.jar at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error for different reason and yes it was due to missing dms.jar file. I just had to find where dms.jar file was on our Oracle Application server (Release 12.2.3) and assigned it to the CLASSPATH. And it worked. Thanks for the pointing to the missing .jar file.

Out .jar file was in $ORACLE_HOME/lib/ folder. Changed the path value as :

CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib/dms.jar and it started working.

Fyi..if it helps anyone i was trying to load BI/XML publisher DATA TEMPLATE using XDOLoader utility when i got this error.

-ppemavath

Answer (score 0):

i too face this problem but when i removed all database related jars and added ojdbc6 (or ojdbc7) jar then application working fine. more details please see below link.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2388722