# Unable to connect to Oracle 11g using jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to Oracle 11g using jdbc as below but its giving me error. I had downloaded and kept jars in eclipse (ojdbc6dms.jar and  ojdbc6dms_g.jar), but still its giving error

```
public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException,
            InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException,
            ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection con = null;

        // initialising drive
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();

        // load driver
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.16.52.79:1521:TST", "rep",
                "Appe");


        String dbName = con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName();

        System.out.println(" Conected to DB " + dbName);

        return con;
    } // insertRecordsToDB


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/dms/console/DMSConsole
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory.<clinit>(DMSFactory.java:45)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createDMSSensors(PhysicalConnection.java:4203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:629)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:218)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:29)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:538)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at
```

Just wondering in which jar has class `oracle/dms/console/DMSConsole` . Because when i checked those jars, this class is not available

Comment: possible duplicate of [where are Oracle's DMS class files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563378/where-are-oracles-dms-class-files)

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC [driver download page for Oracle 11g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html) has the file ojdbc6dms.jar which contains oracle.jdbc.driver.DMSFactory.

EDIT: As per @JavaGeek's comment below, this jar does not actually contain the DMSConsole class.  The required class is available in the Oracle Server installation, in the location `$ORACLE_HOME/oc4j/lib/dms.jar`.  Server downloads are also available at [Oracle TechNetwork](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: But ojdbc6dms.jar it doesn't have class oracle/dms/console/DMSConsole

Comment: Worked after adding dms.jar in eclipse. dms.jar is available in Oracle Server ( not client) location $ORACLE_HOME/oc4j/lib/dms.jar

Comment: As JavaGeek noted, this download is promising, but it simply does not contain the needed class.